# How to create mutable .NET strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string

.NET strings are always immutable, but how can one make an equivalent `System.String` class that the string values can be mutated?

For example: When `a` is changed, I want `b` also be changed.

```
var a = "Hello";
var b = a;
a = "World";
var shouldBeTrue = String.ReferenceEquals(a, b) 
                   && String.Equals(b, "World");
```

Comment: This is not mutating a string, this is having two variables pointing to the same string. You can have that with [ref locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) (`string a = "Hello"; ref string b = ref a;`).

Comment: @GSerg: Wich would work fine if String as any normal reference type. Rather then the single least reference like reference type in the .NET Framework.

Comment: GSerg is right; what you are looking for is not mutable strings at all. What you are looking for is *variable aliases*, that is, having two names `a` and `b` for the same variable. C# 7 supports that.

Comment: This is the result of many C# tutorials incorrectly explaining what immutable means.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are inmutable, wich was a very important design Decisions. It helps using them in Multitasking contexts and allows a bunch of other Optimizations like String Interning.

Usualy the inmutabiltiy is not a problem. Unless you are doing loads of string operations, what little dead strings accumulate can be dealt with by the GC whenver it coems around to running.

For the remaining cases, there is the [StringBuilder class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). Whose purpsoe is to get around inmutability and stuff like internening. On a more extreme level you might make your own Char list or array. Just do not forget to provide a custom ToString(). But for at least 95% of all cases the String and StringBuilder classes are enough.

Edit:

After reading a Comment to your Originbal post, I too noticed that mutabiltiy does not seem to be what you are actually looking for. Rather then you seem to look for is normal reference mechanics. While this thematic is somewhat related to inmutability, it is actually a distinct property. ref should work. As would be just making a class with a single string field and handing the instances of that class around.

Answer (score 0):

As @Christopher noted, most likely what you really want is not string mutability, but rather a reference mechanic by which multiple such references are kept synchronized. The simplest such mechanism would be a wrapper class, like in the example below:

```
    class Wrapper
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wrapper a = new Wrapper();
        a.Value = "Hello";
        Wrapper b = a;
        a.Value = "World";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(a, b));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(a.Value == b.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of the `Wrapper` you could use the built-in [`StrongBox<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.strongbox-1).

Comment: the classic "every problem in computer science can be solved by one more level of indirection"

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "Hello";
var b = a;
var chars = new char[] { 'W','o','r','l','d' };
unsafe
{
    fixed (char* pTempChars = &a.GetPinnableReference())
    {
        char* ptr = pTempChars;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            (*ptr) = chars[i];
            ptr++;
        }
    }
}

var shouldBeTrue = String.ReferenceEquals(a, b) && String.Equals(b, "World");
//shouldBeTrue is true
```

But it can be dangerous. You must be sure that no one other than b and a refers to them. And it only works if the length of the string is the same.

Update(More readable but less flexible):

```
var a = "Hello";
var b = a;
ChangeString(ref a, "World");
var shouldBeTrue = String.ReferenceEquals(a, b) && String.Equals(b, "World");
//shouldBeTrue is true
___________________
var a = "Hello";
var b = a;
ChangeString(ref a, "Wor");
//b == "Worlo"

private bool ChangeString(ref string original, in string newValue)
{
    if(original.Length < newValue.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    unsafe
    {
        fixed (char* pDest = original, pSource = newValue)
        {
            Buffer.MemoryCopy(
                pSource,
                pDest,
                original.Length * sizeof(char),
                newValue.Length * sizeof(char)
                );
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

System.Text.StringBuilder Class is a mutable string. You can use the indexer to change the char in pos (one char only), and use the Insert, Replace, Append, and AppendLine to make changes to the StringBuilder itself in the fastest way possible. These methods return an instance to the same string builder object, so, you don't actually need to assign the return value.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question the way I read the original title of the post.  But:  Any Reference check in .NET is playing with fire.   String.RefrenceCheck can produce different results in debug vs release for example. I also would presume the String vs StringBuilder casts would kick in and give you the wrong reference anyways (it would not appear to be constant object ref with StringBuilder).  Object ref in .NET as part of our app level code is scary.